# QlikView application in web browser. How?

Tags: qlikview

I am very new to QlikView.

I have created a test QlikView application. I wonder, is it possible to access the application in a web browser? If yes, how?

Answer (score 15):

You created a test QlikView application on Qlikview personal version, right?
If you want to access this applicatio in a web browser, you need set up a Qlikview server. However, Qlikview server is not free.

Answer (score 2):

Like mentioned above you need a server. This is a bit too much for private use, but a small enterprise setup is affordable and more important will be worth it. You have experienced what QlikView can do on your stand-alone setup, just imagine what it would mean for a company...

Also with the server come some nice features to automate the reloading of the data in the application (e.g. every night). This is really nice to keep your stuff up to date. In a previous company we also did a lot of ETL with it. QlikView is a nice tool.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see how the application looks in the browser you can view it from the desktop itself.

You have a web view on the Design Menu bar. If you enable that then you can view it like in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

For this you must installation of qlikview server.
you can read about it [here](https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-5291)

Comment: Can you post some content from the link?

Comment: Qlikview server is diffrernt product and among other things its let you show youe document in the browser.